# Amazon Route 53 Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone in Amazon Route 53 service and a domain name on a registrar.

In the registrar, my DNS configurations are correctly inserted, with the four address provided by AWS when I create the hosted zone.

In the Route 53 control panel, I have the **NS** and **SOA** proper configured as it came configured when I created the hosted zone.

I also created a **A Redirection** :  mydomain.com.br  -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (elastic IP)

I'm able to reach my EC2 instance with the A Record: If I type mydomain.com.br on browser it works fine.

My problem is that I'm unable to reach the **CNAME's** that I've created.

I have a CNAME rule: www.mydomain.com.br -> mydomain.com.br/site but when I put www.mydomain.com.br I get a DNS error on my browser.

The strangest thing is that if I consult www.mydomain.com.br on a site like https://www.whatsmydns.net it points to www.mydomain.com.br/site, which is the correct redirect.  The DNS resolution aparently works fine, but I can't get it on the browser.

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

ps: I alredy tried to ipconfig/flushdns and clear chrome's cache

Comment: it sounds like your upstream DNS server has the entry cached.

Comment: @tedder42 And how can I solve this?

Comment: make sure your TTLs are short and/or wait a day.

Comment: The TTL's for the CNAME rules are at 300 seconds =/

Comment: Are you willing to share with us your domain name so we can query the DNS records and see exactly what is happening?

Comment: for sure @BruceP .. my domain is bptechnologies.com.br ... the CNAME that doesnt work is www.bptechnologies.com.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Delete that CNAME record

- Add an A record in Route53
- Name the A record 'www'    it should automatically make that www.mydomain.com.br.
- Check the ALIAS-yes box
- Select mydomain.com.br. from the dropdown box  (note there is a PERIOD on the end)
- Save and Wait about 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok @greg_diesel , you did the job! But one question: a A Record only let me redirect to a IP ... what if I want a redirect like www.bptechnologies.com.br -> bptechnologies.com.br/site  ?

Comment: HTTP redirects and DNS are two different protocols.  DNS does not do redirects.  You can either do it in your web server on ec2 or as Ryan suggested using s3.

Answer (score 0):

A better (and still very cheap) way to do this might be to set up a 301 redirect in an Amazon S3 bucket.  Here is a link to Amazon's tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "www" A record which is pointed to your EIP?